# Selenium webdriver automation test gives Error: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing

My selenium test cases are written in JavaScript for testing my react application but it gives unusual error

1. Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:713 GetBluetoothAdapterStaticsActivationFactory failed: Class not registered (0x80040154).
2. :ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [09:24:47.641] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F).
3. Also it is not able to click few buttons.

Comment: could you post the code snippet you've tried.